# CTC i3 Y-axis thin / no filament deposition

Tags: prusa-i3, pla, y-axis, underextrusion

I have this CTC i3 printer; when I print square test prints, as it moves along the Y-axis back to zero (front). It extrudes lines but very thin or none at all.

But opposite direction along the Y axis is 100 %

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can see a couple of problems in your images:

1. Your bed is clearly and awfully unleveled. Check on Youtube some manual leveling using a paper.
2. Though I think your problems will be solved by correct leveling, if not, check [this](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/13463/raised-lines-on-top-layer-surface-ender-3/13517#13517) thread where I explain a little bit about E-step and flow rate calibration. Having these parameters right is crucial for a good first layer.
3. I don't know what you are using for layer adhesion but if after doing steps 1 and 2 the problem persists I would heat up a little bit the bed and change the adhesion material (glue, hairspray).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the first image, it appears that the nozzle is a little too close to the glass build plate. You clearly see that the nozzle scrapes over the glass and filament is deposited on either side of the nozzle. Re-level the bed with a (thicker) piece of paper or with a feeler gauge. Alternatively, increase the height of the nozzle by re-defining the height or add an extra Z raise in the slicer (see question: "[How can I add an offset to the first layer to increase clearance?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/13330/how-can-i-add-an-offset-to-the-first-layer-to-increase-clearance/13334)").